# Two Dimensional Curve Approximation

Tags: geometry, curve, approximation

here is what I want to do (preferably with Matlab):

Basically I have several traces of cars driving on an intersection. Each one is noisy, so I want to take the mean over all measurements to get a better approximation of the real route. In other words, I am looking for a way to approximate the Curve, which has the smallest distence to all of the meassured traces (in a least-square sense).

At the first glance, this is quite similar what can be achieved with spap2 of the CurveFitting Toolbox (good example in section *Least-Squares Approximation* [here](http://www.mathworks.de/products/curvefitting/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/curvefit/splexmpl.html#20)).
But this algorithm has some major drawback: It assumes a function (with exactly one y(x) for every x), but what I want is a curve in 2d (which may have several y(x) for one x). This leads to problems when cars turn right or left with more then 90 degrees.
Futhermore it takes the vertical offsets and not the perpendicular offsets (according to the definition on [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html)).

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem? I thought of using a B-Spline and change the number of knots and the degree until I reached a certain fitting quality, but I can't find a way to solve this problem analytically or with the functions provided by the CurveFitting Toolbox. Is there a way to solve this without numerical optimization?

Comment: Could you make each path a function of time?  For each time value, a car would only have one (x,y) coordinate.

Comment: This yields to the problem, that every car drives with a different speed. If t=0 is set at a given point ahead of the intersection, one car may already have finished the turning manoever, while the other (more carefully car) has not after the same amount of time. As a consequence, the mean of (x,y) of both cars at the same time doesn't lead to a curve with the smallest distance (in the x-y-plane) to the measured traces .

Comment: I was thinking instead of averaging different cars' paths, you could just filter the high frequency noise out of each path to make them smooth.

Answer (score 0):

mbeckish is right. In order to get sufficient flexibility in the curve shape, you must use a parametric curve representation (x(t), y(t)) instead of an explicit representation y(x). See [Parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).

Given n successive points on the curve, assign them their true time if you know it or just integers 0..n-1 if you don't. Then call spap2 twice with vectors T, X and T, Y instead of X, Y. Now for arbitrary t you get a point (x, y) on the curve.

This won't give you a true least squares solution, but should be good enough for your needs.

Comment: This implies that all the cars are traveling at the same speed, since it assumes that for different paths (x_i(t_0), y_i(t_0)) are close to each other for all paths i and times t_0. I think you need a way of doing the averaging that also allows the paths to be reparameterized.